# List Clang-Query Matchers

Tags: compiler-construction, static-analysis, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang-query

Is there a way to list all possible matchers in `clang-query`? The [AST matcher reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) list is not necessarily the most up-to-date version. Even the list in `ASTMatchers.h` clang header (`clang-6.0.0`) does not show what is currently available. For example, the `equalsNode` matcher is included in the list, while it is not available in `clang-query`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the matchers have defects and are still in progress. Therefore, although their names are included in the `ASTMatchers.h` header file, they can not be used. This can be deduced from the following comment at `clang-6.0.0/lib/ASTMatchers/Dynamic/Registry.cpp:Line 95`:

```
// TODO: Here is the list of the missing matchers, grouped by reason.
//
// Need Variant/Parser fixes:
// ofKind
//
// Polymorphic + argument overload:
// findAll
//
// Other:
// equalsNode

REGISTER_OVERLOADED_2(callee);
...
```

As can be seen, `equalsNode` is also one of the missing matchers. The supported matchers are registered in the following lines.